# Warning FailedScheduling 12s (x3 over 13s) default-scheduler 0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match node selector

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, skaffold, harbor

I'm stuck deploying the microservices locally with the following stack: *Skaffold, minikube, helm, and harbor*.
These microservices can be deployed locally without any problem with docker and docker-compose.
When I run **skaffold dev**, it stop at this point:

`- statefulset/service0: Waiting for 1 pods to be ready...`

When I describe the pod with the command:
**kubectl describe pod service-0**

```
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  12s (x3 over 13s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match node selector.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong... Any ideas?

Comment: "0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match node selector." - have you set any `nodeSelector` ?

Answer (score 1):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes/

Assign labels to a node to match your manifest or alter your manifest to match the `nodeSelector` statement in your YAML.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was solved by running this command:

```
kubectl label node <node-name> role=server
```

in my case:

```
kubectl label nodes minikube role=server
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).